# I am trying to import torch-cpu in python 3.9 but get the following error

Tags: python, importerror, torch, oserror, python-3.9

On trying to `import torch-cpu`, the following error is raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import torch   File "C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)   File "C:\Users\Ravi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: hi dude, I think this link may help, https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/27693

Comment: Hi @Puspender Singh if you find any of the answers helpful please mark it as such (gray tick mark on the left of the question). Please consider also upvoting the useful answers too.

Answer (score 0):

As Akash pointed out the issue is likely related to the order in which your Python root folders are listed in `%PATH%`. There is likely a different version of Python (3.8 in this case) referred earlier that causes Python 3.9 to load libraries that were not installed for this version (hence likely incompatible).

To fix it make Python 3.9 root directory the first on your `%PATH%`.